# How can I feed last output y(t-1) as input for generating y(t) in tensorflow RNN?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I want to design a single layer RNN in Tensorflow such that last output `(y(t-1))` is participated in updating the hidden state.

```
h(t) = tanh(W_{ih} * x(t) + W_{hh} * h(t) + **W_{oh}y(t - 1)**)
y(t) = W_{ho}*h(t)
```

How can I feed last input `y(t - 1)` as input for updating the hidden state?

Comment: Currently, I am looking into this tutorial which seems promising: https://github.com/ematvey/tensorflow-seq2seq-tutorials/blob/master/2-seq2seq-advanced.ipynb

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681026/tensorflow-how-to-pass-output-from-previous-time-step-as-input-to-next-timestep/49274234#49274234

Answer (score 2):

Is y(t-1) the last input or output? In both cases it is not a straight fit with the TensorFlow RNN cell abstraction. If your RNN is simple you can just write the loop on your own, then you have full control. Another way that I would use is to pre-process your RNN input, e.g., do something like:

> processed_input[t] = tf.concat(input[t], input[t-1])

Then call the RNN cell with processed_input and split there.

Comment: It uses the last generated output by itself. How can I write a loop for a simple RNN? In the way that the behind-the-scene optimizations be ok.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use `tf.nn.raw_rnn` which I found in this [article](https://hanxiao.github.io/2017/08/16/Why-I-use-raw-rnn-Instead-of-dynamic-rnn-in-Tensorflow-So-Should-You-0/). Check my answer to this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681026/tensorflow-how-to-pass-output-from-previous-time-step-as-input-to-next-timestep/49274234#49274234).

Answer (score 0):

I would call what you described an "autoregressive RNN". Here's an (incomplete) code snippet that shows how you can create one using `tf.nn.raw_rnn`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

LSTM_SIZE = 128
BATCH_SIZE = 64
HORIZON = 10

lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(LSTM_SIZE, use_peepholes=True)


class RnnLoop:
    def __init__(self, initial_state, cell):
        self.initial_state = initial_state
        self.cell = cell

    def __call__(self, time, cell_output, cell_state, loop_state):
        emit_output = cell_output  # == None for time == 0
        if cell_output is None:  # time == 0
            initial_input = tf.fill([BATCH_SIZE, LSTM_SIZE], 0.0)
            next_input = initial_input
            next_cell_state = self.initial_state
        else:
            next_input = cell_output
            next_cell_state = cell_state

        elements_finished = (time >= HORIZON)
        next_loop_state = None
        return elements_finished, next_input, next_cell_state, emit_output, next_loop_state


rnn_loop = RnnLoop(initial_state=initial_state_tensor, cell=lstm_cell)
rnn_outputs_tensor_array, _, _ = tf.nn.raw_rnn(lstm_cell, rnn_loop)
rnn_outputs_tensor = rnn_outputs_tensor_array.stack()
```

Here we initialize internal state of LSTM with some vector `initial_state_tensor`, and feed zero array as input at `t=0`. After that, the output of the current timestep is the input for the next timestep.

Comment: How would you implement this in Keras @Alexey Petrenko?

Comment: Not sure about Keras, but this is absolutely trivial in PyTorch! :D