# Tensorflow: Delay variable over training steps

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

In Tensorflow, I want to use some of the variables of my network from the previous training step in the next training step. More specifically, I want to calculate a secondary cost function during training which utilizes some network tensors from the previous training step.

This question could be answered with fragments of RNN code, but I didn't figure out how yet. I was looking into [How can I feed last output y(t-1) as input for generating y(t) in tensorflow RNN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145645/how-can-i-feed-last-output-yt-1-as-input-for-generating-yt-in-tensorflow-rnn#) and [Tensorflow: How to pass output from previous time-step as input to next timestep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681026/tensorflow-how-to-pass-output-from-previous-time-step-as-input-to-next-timestep) as well as [TensorFlow: Remember LSTM state for next batch (stateful LSTM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241410/tensorflow-remember-lstm-state-for-next-batch-stateful-lstm).

Assume h is the last layer of a neural network with several previous layers, e.g.:

```
h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_previous,W_previous))
```

How could I preserve the tensor h after processing a sample during training (e.g. save it to h_old), so that I can use it in the next training step for a computation like:

```
d = tf.sub(h,h_old)
```

In this example h is updated with the current training sample and h_old is the tensor which was computed on the previous training sample. Some ideas for this issue would be great!

Answer (score 0):

How about making `h_old` a variable?

```
h_old = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(<some-shape>))

.
.

h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_previous,W_previous))
d = tf.sub(h,h_old)
h_old.assign(h)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will test this as soon as possible. I will let you know if this really works for this problem.